# Remove all elements binded to object

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I have some IInputElement placed on my canvas in WPF. Also I have many other IInputElements binded to the main one. Once I remove the main IInputElement from canvas, how can I remove also all objects which are binded to the main one? I was trying to remove them using

```
ClearValue(MyProperty)
```

but that doesn't helped at all.

Comment: How do you create the elements you want to remove?

Comment: Using my constructor, where I set binding to main IInputElement and adding new object to canvas' children

Comment: Hard to suggest a proper solution with no real context of the app. For eg: you could when you create these new objects that are binding to the main element, just add a reference to them from the main object. That way when you want to remove your main element it already knows all it's linked items and can call remove on them before removing itself. It's just one simple solution, You could also before removing the main element, iterate through your canvas's children and find all items currently bound to the main one and remove them when a match is found